# Visualising 2 Independent Variables and 1 Dependent Variable

Tags: python, data-visualization

I'm trying to come up with the best way to graphically display misfits from multiple geophysical inversion runs, where I am fixing two independent variables and analysing the misfit of each test.  For example, the test structure may look like

```
        Var1  Var2  Misfit (%)
Test 1    8    1.5   13.5
          8    2.0   12.4
          8    2.5   10.1

        Var1  Var2  Misfit (%)
Test 2    10   1.5   20.4
          10   2.0   23.1
          10   2.5   15.0
        Var1  Var2  Misfit (%)
Test 3    12   1.5    5.5
          12   2.0    8.9
          12   2.5   17.5
```

What would be the best way to graphically display these tests?  The objective is to better understand trends in misfit given the two independent variables, `Var1` and `Var2`.
I'm thinking I could set different colours for `Var1`, set the x-axis to `Var2`, and then set the y-axis to `Misfit`.
If anyone has any experience with this sort of testing and visualization, any recommendations is appreciated!  I will most likely be working with Python or Python Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Since your DV is `Misfit`, using `Var1` and `Var2` as your `x-y` axes, and *coloring* `Misfit`, i.e. your `z` and with a suitable colormap would be the best to obtain an intuition how your DVs combined effect look like.

Specific to Python, you can use `matplotlib` scatter plots with `c` argument as your color variable. For example, in your case, assume we have a dataframe with columns `Var1`,`Var2` and `MisFit`:

```
`plt.scatter(df.Var1,df.Var2,c=df.MisFit)`
```

Comment: With python 3,the code is plt.scatter(df['Var1'],df['Var2'],c=df['MisFit'])`